A novel about an asteroid-looking automated spaceship larger inside than outside
I read this novel more than 20 years ago, in French, but I am convinced it was a translation from English. It might even be older than that. It was a pretty fat paperback, but I don't remember the cover.
The story is long and complicated, and I remember very little.
Some object from distant space arrives near Earth and somehow ends up in a stable orbit around Earth, which is physically impossible for an "unanimated object", so people realise that it is not just an ordinary asteroid.
Missions are sent to it, IIRC, both from the US and the USSR (yes, the novel was old enough !)
They find, as expected, that it is a spaceship, but automated. Whatever civilisation built it has left it empty of life, though full of unknown technology.
The most salient aspect of this spaceship is that it is much larger inside than as measured from the outside.

This is a very strong match for Eon by Greg Bear, it was published in 1985 so fits your timescale. It also features an asteroid type space craft in a stable orbit around the earth and missions from both the US ands USSR investigate.
The object is as you say much larger on the inside than the outside.

In the view of the Wiki page, it is indeed clearly my story
